# How to override toString() method twice in the same entity

Tags: java, primefaces, tostring

JSF 2.1
PrimeFaces 3.5

I have two primefaces autocomplete controls with two differente fields in the same entity

```
<p:autoComplete id="ida" minQueryLength="4"
value="#{bean.enterprise.field1}"

<p:autoComplete id="idb" minQueryLength="4"
value="#{bean.enterprise.field2}"
```

i.e. : Enterprise entity has two fields (field1 and field2)

entity :

```
@Column(name="field1", length=100,nullable=false)
private String field1;

@Column(name="field2", length=100,nullable=false)
private String field2;

@Override
public String toString(){
return this.field1;
}
```

In Enterprise entity I have the toString() method overrided with field1

*The question is : How to override also the field 1 and field2 in the same entity*. Thats because I need to show the field 1 and field 2 values in the controls.

If I dont override the toString Method field1 I get in my view the object value and not the field value :
[image]

Comment: you cannot override the `toString` method for the same class. What are field1 and field2 exactly?

Comment: lets assume you can do it, when you want to execute first and second `toString()` ?

Comment: the view will be rendered and will show both field values

Comment: can you just create getter for each value, and use them instead `toString`?

Comment: @user902383 , he is using `jsf` so the call `"#{bean.enterprise.field1}"` will itself call the `getField1()` method

Comment: @Al2x, argghh... can't see the image right now :(

Comment: Ive updated image again @PrasadKharkar

Comment: @Al2x, I think the problem is with your `completeMethod`. Make sure that method is returning a `List<String>` in which you are passing list of field 1 or field2. Can you please add your completeMethod?

Comment: public <T> List<T> autoCompleteQuery(T query) {  
        List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();  searchengine.xxxx(); return results; @PrasadKharkar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37127/discussion-between-prasad-kharkar-and-al2x)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to do anything, if you just want String representation of fields. They are already `String`

You are accessing using `"#{bean.enterprise.field1}"`, both fields are `String` so they will be output in the autocomplete properly.

I may have missed something about primefaces autocomplete functionality here.
You can refer [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf;jsessionid=qrpjerghvicy1vqbio08vnqwa)

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedValue}" id="someId" completeMethod="#{someBean.completeMethod}"/>
```

Notice the `completeMethod` must return the string value in your case

Comment: If I dont override toString() method, the #{bean.enterprise.field1} returns in my view the object string instead the object value @Prasad Kharkar

Comment: @Al2x, from the code , I see that type of `field1` is `String` so your value itself is `String` so `#{bean.enterprise.field1}` will return `String`